# Why is $\log n = O(2^n)$?

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

In my theoretical computer science book I have the following statement regarding the **space complexity** of $f(n)=2^n$:

$$\log(n) = O(f(n))$$

I can't understand how this is true, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that the question is purely about the relationships between the functions $\log n$ and $2^n$. It doesn't matter if those functions are being used to measure time complexity, space complexity or the number of seconds until a radioactive source decays. It's just about the two functions.

Comment: The context is obscure. Where, in what book? What is the theme/chapter title?

Comment: What is the connection to space complexity?

Comment: Are you asking why does $\log n = O(2^n)$ holds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated, $\log (n) = O (2^n)$ is trivially true.

All that it says is that $\log n$, in the end, grows no faster than $2^n$. For $2^n$, you can substitute $n$, $\sqrt n$, indeed any root of $n$.

---

However carelessly stated, I think this really refers to the following:

- To represent a number of size $2^n$, you need $n$ bits.
- So, to represent a number of size $n$, you need $\log n$ bits.

Bits are a measure of space.

---

I made heavy weather of this before, as I thought it was referring to the time it takes to calculate $2^n$. In case it is, I'll leave this in:

For $n$ a non-negative integer, and $f(n) = 2^n$

$$
f(n) = 
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{for }\, n = 0 \\
(f (n \div 2))^2\times 2^{(n \mod 2)} &\text{for}\; n \gt 0
\end{cases}$$

The implied algorithm is clearly $\Theta (log \, n)$. But this is *time* complexity. In *space* complexity, it is $\Theta(1)$.

---

- $\Theta (f)$ are the functions that, adapting the words of Wolfram
  Mathworld, are no worse but also no better than $f$.
- $O (f)$ are the functions that are no worse than $f$.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: You are still avoiding the question.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I look forward to your solution.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus It appears that Thumbnail has indeed answered the question, or at least one possible interpretation. $2^n$ in binary is, of course, 1 followed by $n$ 0s, so it would suffice to represent $n$, using $\log n$ bits. Thus one might say that the space complexity of $2^n$ is at most $\log n$. I would readily admit that this is just one interpretation of what could be described as an obfuscated question at best.